# Why does a templated rvalue reference accept lvalues?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I saw the usage of something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename FN>
void Foo(FN&& Fn)
{
    Fn();
}


void b()
{
    cout << "2." << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    Foo([](){ cout << "1." << endl; });
    Foo(&b);

    auto c = []() { cout << "3." << endl; };

    Foo(c);

    std::function<void(void)> d = c;

    Foo(d);

    return 0;
}
```

I am fairly sure 'c' is an lvalue, but I could believe that there was some lambda type deduction shenanigans. But I am almost 100% sure, d is an lvalue.

Why does the templated stuff work if the function takes in an rvalue, but d is an lvalue?

Furthermore why would one write Foo's signature like that instead of just

```
template<typename FN>
void Foo(FN Fn)
```

Comment: It's not really an rvalue: it's called "universal reference" (or "forwading reference", but the former expresses the idea better) due to template type deduction and reference collapsing.

Comment: @black The correct term is "forwarding reference" (because it should probably be `std::forward()`-ed). "Universal reference" is something that Scott Meyers uses.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for deduction of `T&&` are tricky.

They where designed to make a deduced `T&&` a "forwarding reference" (or "universal reference").

First, reference collapsing.  Suppose you have an unknown type X.  For now `X` is not deduced.

Then if we examine variables of the following type:

```
typedef X x0;
typedef X& x1;
typedef X const& x2;
typedef X&& x3;
```

and we set `X` to be one of `int`, `int&`, `int const&` and `int&&`, we get:

```
X is --->  int         int&      int const&      int&&
X          int         int&      int const&      int&&
X&         int&        int&      int const&      int&
X const&   int const&  int&      int const&      int&
X&&        int&&       int&      int const&      int&&
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b8f1f7859c260d4).

The next bit comes with the deduction rules.  If you pass `X&` to `T&&` in a deduced context, `T` is deduced to be `X&`.  This causes `T&&` to become `X&` by the above reference collapsing rules.  Similar things happen for `X const&`.

If you pass `X&&` to `T&&`, it deduces `T` to be `X`.  `T&&` becomes `X&&` as well.

Between the two of them, in a deduced context, `template<class T> void foo(T&&t)` is a universal reference (well, now called a forwarding reference).

You can recover the r/l value category of `t` with `std::forward<T>(t)`, hence the name forwarding reference.

This allows one template to process both l and r values, and use `std::forward` and similar machinery to behave slightly differently, if you want.

Only processing rvalues requires extra work: you have to use SFINAE or another overload (possibly with `=delete`).  Only processing lvalues is easy (just deduce with `T&`).